# ionic application does not serve or even execute commands in ubuntu

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

i have a problem i was updating my ionic environmet and ionic beta was successfully installed by when i try running the ionic serve --lab it cannot serve the application, it generates an error below , how can i fix it, thank you, i wil be glad for your help.

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:6
process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.log(r));
                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:124:16)
    at node.js:807:3
```

Comment: Having the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

same for me, were you getting warnings around your NodeJs version too?

Upgrade your version of nodejs and this should fix your issue https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/04/29/how-to-upgrade-nodejs-mac-os-x/